# Does a non-Alolan Pikachu evolve into an Alolan Raichu or a normal Raichu?

Tags: pokemon-seventh-generation

Doing some preparation for when my Ultra Moon game comes, I have caught a Pikachu i n Y (So i can max EV train it) and I was wondering that if I trade it to UM will it still evolve into an Alolan Raichu if the Thunderstone is used there?

Answer (score 4):

Transferring an older generation Pikachu and evolving it in US/UM will result in an Alolan Raichu, not a non-Alolan variant. To obtain the non-Alolan variant, [you have to evolve it whilst in Ultra Space](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Regional_variant). Being from an older generation does not make a difference. This also means that there is [no way to evolve a Pikachu in Sun/Moon](https://www.serebii.net/sunmoon/alolaforms.shtml) into non-Alolan Pikachu without trading it to US/UM, since Sun/Moon doesn't have Ultra Space.

This also applies to Exeggcute and Cubone.

Comment: According to the wiki Alolan Marowak is a nighttime evolution only.

Comment: @IG_42 That's true, but it still won't evolve into normal Marowak even during the day unless you're in Ultra Space